# HTML hyperlink are not available in Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Using Java I can able to generate the word Jasper report where I have HTML links (used to go from one place to another place). I have already set markup property as HTML.

```
JRDocxExporter newExporter = new JRDocxExporter();
newExporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrintList);
newExporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "REPORT_NAME" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".docx");
newExporter.exportReport();
```

With same jrxml, I am exported the word document from struts action. I am not able to get the HTML links in document. I don't know what is the issue. I have tried with several content type.

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
..
..
..
ServletOutputStream outputStream = null;
outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JRDocxExporter docExporter = new JRDocxExporter();
docExporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrintList);
docExporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, byteArrayOutputStream);
docExporter.setParameter(JRDocxExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, REPORT_NAME);
docExporter.exportReport();
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
response.setContentType("application/ms-word");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + REPORT_NAME + "\"");
outputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
response.flushBuffer();
```

Answer (score 1):

In JasperReports, only text field, image, and chart elements can be hyperlinks or anchors. Can you check the type of field(static text field or text field) that you have used for hyperlink?

Comment: thanks. It is TextField only . Inside text field multiple anchors hyper links are there.